# Number of Occurrence of a Substring in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a column with some words separated by comma. I would like to count the number of occurrences of each word like this -

```
animals      count_cats  count_dogs
cats             1           0
cats,dogs        1           1
dogs,cats,dogs   1           2
```

How do I achieve this in Tableau?

I created a calculated field following the instructions here - https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/counting-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-dimension - but that would return either 1 or 0 since the CONTAINS function returns True or False.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this.

For `count_dogs` use this calculation instead

```
(LEN([Animals])-
LEN(REPLACE([Animals], 'dogs', '')))/
LEN('dogs')
```

[image]

You can also do a parameteric count, by using the following calculation (`param` is paramaeter)

```
(LEN([Animals])-
LEN(REPLACE([Animals], [param], '')))/
LEN([param])
```

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Please upvote, as usually desired on SO.